# CORS Allow-Access-Control-Origin on Mobile Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cors

I am getting an error on mobile, when I use Chrome to try out my new responsive web app. I have done everything from add php headers in several different ways, to passing headers in my ajax request. On the web, I used CORS toggle, a Chrome extension that allows you to toggle on and off CORS, which fixes the problem on web. Yet I cannot seem to find a solution like this for mobile. Anyway I can bypass CORS on mobile Chrome??

I have tried ALL of these ways, and nothing seems to work..

php option 1:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST');
?>
```

php option 2:

```
<?php
    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

    echo "You have CORS!";
?>
```

jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '<MY API ENDPOINT>',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "GET, PUT, POST",
            'Authorization':
              'Bearer <MY TOKEN>',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
          },
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false
        }).done(function(res) {
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are set by the server not the client, so adding them to your ajax call does nothing. And is _"MY API ENDPOINT"_ on your own server? If not then setting the headers in your php does nothing as well.

Comment: I am using salesforces' api.einstein.ai/v2/vision/predict

Answer (score -1):

Remove the access control headers from your ajax request. Access control headers are automatically set by the browser as defined in the W3C CORS spec.

Whatever headers you include in your ajax request, you need to allow in the server response. In your case it's `Authorization` and `Cache-Control`. Add them to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Use option 2 of your php code. It includes a response for the cors preflight OPTIONS request. Option 1 will not work for that reason.